# Can I use SketchUp with a Macbook's trackpad?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

Sketchup is designed for use with a third mouse button (particularly the pan and orbit functions).  Can I emulate the third button for SketchUp using a MacBook's trackpad or user gestures?

Comment: Confession: Asking this question mainly because I always forget, and the top results on Google don't seem to answer the question right... Maybe I'll see this next time I'm searching.  And maybe it will help someone else! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes!

- Orbit - Cmd+Ctrl and click/drag
- Pan - Cmd+Ctrl+Shift and click/drag
- Zoom - Two-finger scroll up/down (no click necessary)

Comment: I wish there were a Sketchup Plugin to allow pinch-zoom, two-finger panning and maybe three-finger orbit.

Comment: Is this configurable?

Comment: @Chet It's been a long time since I answered this question - at the time, I don't think it was configurable. If you find that it is configurable, let us know! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that as long as you keep finger contact on the trackpad, you can release the keys and still continue to Pan or Orbit.

If you release your touch on the pad, as happens if you cannot go any further in the limited space, then you have to use the keys again to get into the desired command, at which point you can release the keys and keep Panning and Orbiting.

Thanks for the question. Your post did the same thing thing for me that you wanted: it showed up first in Google search to remind me of the correct keyboard commands. My normal workstation has a 3-button mouse just for SU, but sometimes I'm on a laptop with no mouse, or only a magic mouse.